# Rails 5 (minitest) handles values different in test than production and development

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails 5.0.0.1 app that has model for books and for authors.
In production and development, the pages display as expected showing the book.author.name
However, in my tests, book.author is valid and as expected, but book.author.name produces an error "ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"

using byebug I found that the author_id for the book is set to 459301548 but there is no author with that id.

How does minitest handle things differently such that the error only occurs in the test environment?

I have tried moving things around and trying different ways to populate @books to use in my @books.each do |book| but the only thing that seems to work is to remove the reference to book.author.name

The error is only occurring when not logged in, but I need to check my tests to make sure that I don't get it in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this makes a difference, but when I change the variable assignment in my controller from:

@books = Book.paginate(...)

to:

@books = Book.all.paginate(...)

The error goes away.
The pages still seems to show the correct information in development and production either way.